# Cloudinary CORS in the new SDK (v2)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, cors, cloudinary, cross-origin-embedder-policy

I am using the *cloudinary* service to display image in my react app by using the new beta of *React SDK v2* to be used with *TS*. I am using the function as depicted in the doc but in return I have

> ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE.NotSameOriginAfterDefaultedToSameOriginByCoep
> 200

Here is my code:

```js
const cld = new Cloudinary({
    cloud: {
        cloudName: "mycloudname",
    }
});
const myImage = cld.image("sample");
```

I am new in CORS usage so i am probably missing something, but in the new SDK I can't find anywhere where i am supposed to add a header to allow CORS.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

The header must be set on the server side and not on the client-side. My assumption is that you're using nodejs environment, below might be useful to you when setting the response header:
https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#responsesetheadername-value

The specific header you're looking to set is: Access-Control-Allow-Origin